# Why there is a need for dedicated syntax (:=, the Walrus operator) for named expressions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I genuinely do not understand why there was a need to introduce a dedicated syntax (the `:=` operator) for named expressions, described in [PEP572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). E.g. one is supposed to write:

```
if (match := pattern.search(data)) is not None:
    # Do something with match
```

why not simply `if (match = pattern.search(data))`? If it is because of backward compatibility, then note that the following expression: `(x = 1)` raises `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, thus it would be enough to allow for it and start interpreting it as a named expression, instead of introducing the new `:=` operator, which btw will in probably most cases be surrounded by parentheses anyway.

I feel like I don't see something obvious that everyone else gets ;-)

Comment: [The page you linked addresses that](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#why-not-just-turn-existing-assignment-into-an-expression)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s because [*explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), and `:=` makes your intentions of performing assignment clear; whereas using `=` could easily be the result of a typo, which is the reason why `=` intentionally does not work in an expression in Python.

In fact, accidentally using `=` instead of `==` inside a comparison is a frequent source of error in languages that support it.

Comment: OK, thanks. As for the classic `=` vs. `==` error, you can't make it in Python, since assignments don't return `True`, which could be by mistake tested in the condition, as it can happen in C/C++, if I recall well.
But you are saying that allowing for `if (x = 1)` would increase chances for confusion with `if (x == 1)`, maybe that is true indeed.

Comment: @Maciek You can’t make this mistake in Python *because* `=` assignment doesn’t return a value. If (as you suggest) Python would allow `=` in expressions instead of requiring use of the `:=` operator, Python would be open to the exact same `=` *vs* `==` error.